# Can't do pattern matching over Option[String] having a different runtime type

Tags: scala

I have a response from a server which I need to do a pattern matching on (REPL):

```
scala> val res = getResponse
res: Option[String] = Some(Some(9a/Fv8kifYPRfQNTTpke4XZiMGCLbbB))
scala> res.getClass
res11: Class[_ <: Option[String]] = class scala.Some
```

But I can't get the value of `Some(Some(x))`. When I say:

```
res.get
```

I get an error of `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Or:

```
scala> res.toString
res15: String = Some(Some(9a/Fv8kifYPRfQNTTpke4XZiMGCLbbBle0Gh73p3TIA=))
```

I could say:

```
val a = res.asInstanceOf[Option[Option[String]]]
a.get.get // or a match { ... }
```

But what there'll be an exception if `res = None`, won't there? Is there a better, more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have wrong cast somewhere inside `getResponse`. It result type is `Option[String]`, but you really get `Option[Option[String]]`.

```
scala> val x = Some(Some("test"))
x: Some[Some[String]] = Some(Some(test))

scala> val y = x.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]
y: Option[String] = Some(Some(test))

scala> y.get
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

As for `a.get.get`, you can `a.flatten` (it gives you Option[String]) and `foreach` or `map` over it.

```
scala> x.flatten
res0: Option[String] = Some(test)

scala> res0 foreach println
test
```

Also, take a look at [Option Cheat List](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Cannot prove that String <:< Option[B]

Comment: You made a mistake, you wanted to do `y.flatten` and it would cause the same exception.

Comment: It works for me on scala 2.10.2. May be you redefined `x`? `flatten` will not work with `y`.

Comment: But `x` is not the same type as `res`. res is Option[String] = Some(Some(9a/Fv8kifYPRfQNTTpke4XZiMGCLbbB)), whereas x is Option[Option[String]] = Some(Some(test))

Comment: No, your exception clearly says that `res` is not `Option[String]`. It's `Option[Option[String]]` explicitly casted somewhere to `Option[String]`. You need to get rid of this cast.

Comment: Nope, it's Option[String] (compile-time type) explicitily casted to Option[Option[String]] (run-time type).

Comment: If you talk about `a` (in your sample), then success of `a.get.get` proves that the real type of `a` is `Option[Option[String]]`. And its current type `Option[String]` is wrong, as I simulated in my sample. Please, check your `getResponse` for explicit type casts.

Comment: getResponse is a library method.

Comment: I'm talking about res, not "a".

Comment: It doesn't matter, `a` is `res` casted to `Option[Option[String]]`.

Comment: a1: Any = 123. What's the type of a1?

Comment: `Int` casted to its superclass `Any`. But it's not relevant to your case, `Option[String]` isn't superclass of `Option[Option[String]]`.

Comment: is not it? `class Option[+A]` is covariant.

Comment: But `String` isn't superclass of `Option[String]` and nor vise versa.